# IE 8 double click with jquery doesn't make any sense and does not trigger click()

Tags: jquery, events, internet-explorer-8, click, cross-browser

I've got IE 8 and I use .click(function(){});
It works perfectly and triggers the event once I click my li.
However if I click two times within a short interval it triggers only once.
I suppose IE 8 thinks it as a "Double click" - well fine if there's such an event, but what I don't get is why it actually cancels my click function...

Is there anyhow I can solve this?..

Comment: Not a bad question but try not to sound so much like you're ranting.

Comment: It also always helps to set up a jsfiddle to display the problem you're having.

Comment: Ok.. sorry, but I was kind of amazed by this behavior... it's so wierd :)

Comment: kk give me a sec we will post it to JS fiddle

Comment: Yeah, anyone who has ever created a decent website has banged their head on a wall on many occasions to make it work in IE when it works... everywhere else.  The thing to remember is if you want help, you need others to take you seriously.

Comment: I can't seem to post it to JS fiddle. Anyway, any kind of help would be still appreciated.

Comment: Solved. I will self answer in 8 hours >.<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var okToClick = true;
$('ul li.arr_d, ul li.arr_u').click(OnDownClick).dblclick(OnDownClick);
function OnDownClick() {
    if (okToClick) {
        okToClick = false;
    //do the stuff here :)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could have jquery's dblclick (double click) event trigger a single click event. If that doesn't work it would suggest that it isn't a double click event problem

Comment: is there any other way I can fix it, without sacrifysing the cross browser compatibility>

Comment: can you get something on jsbin etc so we can look at the full code?